# How to replace database configuration in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I Have mad an installer for my website. but I don't how to replace `hostname`,`username`, `password` and `database`. with the values which are coming from input fields.
This is the code from `config/database.php` file.

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'db_host',
    'username' => 'db_user',
    'password' => 'db_pass',
    'database' => 'db_name',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

but this code gives me that error.

[image]

and this code in `controller`.

```
function configure_database() {
    // write database.php
    $data_db = file_get_contents('./application/config/database.php');
   // session_start();
    $data_db = str_replace('db_name',   $_POST['dbname'],   $data_db);
    $data_db = str_replace('db_user',   $_POST['username'], $data_db);
    $data_db = str_replace('db_pass',   $_POST['password'], $data_db);
    $data_db = str_replace('db_host',   $_POST['hostname'], $data_db);
    file_put_contents('./application/config/database.php', $data_db);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could format the `config/database.php` as follows :

```
$db['default']['username'] = "%USERNAME%";
$db['default']['password'] = "%PASSWORD%";
$db['default']['database'] = "%DATABASE%";
$db['default']['hostname'] = "%HOSTNAME%";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysqli";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

Then write to it using this method :

```
function configure_database() {
    // write database.php
    $data_db = file_get_contents('config/database.php');
    // session_start();
    $temporary = str_replace("%DATABASE%", $_POST['dbname'],   $data_db);
    $temporary = str_replace("%USERNAME%", $_POST['username'], $temporary);
    $temporary = str_replace("%PASSWORD%", $_POST['password'], $temporary);
    $temporary = str_replace("%HOSTNAME%", $_POST['hostname'], $temporary);
    // Write the new database.php file
    $output_path = './application/config/database.php';
    $handle = fopen($output_path,'w+');
    // Chmod the file, in case the user forgot
    @chmod($output_path,0777);
    // Verify file permissions
    if(is_writable($output_path)) {
        // Write the file
        if(fwrite($handle,$temporary)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Basically it checks on every line for a match and then replace them with the posted data, and lastly write it to the database config again.

Reference : [CodeIgniter Installer](https://github.com/mikecrittenden/codeigniter-installer)

Answer (score 0):

> If you would like to dynamically set a config item or change an existing one, you can do so using:
>
> `$this->config->set_item('item_name', 'item_value');`
>
> Where item_name is
>   the $config array index you want to change, and item_value is its
>   value.

So you can try this:

```
 // validate the input
 if(isset($_POST['dbname']){
     $this->config->set_item('hostname',$_POST['dbname']);
 }
 ...
```